# Reference for complex analysis jargon

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I am not a (complex) analyst but it seems that some of the questions I am working on are related to the following concepts:

1. logarithmic capacity
2. transfinite diameter
3. Green's function of a compact set
4. System of Fekete points
5. upper regularization

I have looked at various books but some of them are very old (e.g., Hille's *Analytic function theory* which was published in 1962), and most of them just explain the subject briefly. I am looking for references which are more on the advanced side rather than elementary, to be able to find in them the results I need.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The question is not the resources of the Book you want to read, Do you have patience to read the book?

Answer (score 8):

I would say these concepts rather belong to the field of potential theory. You will find most of the definitions and a fairly advanced treatment of the subject in [*Logarithmic Potentials with External Fields*](http://books.google.com/books?id=0-pJz_ntKH4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=Logarithmic+potentials+with+external+fields&hl=en&ei=2hRQTcrvBIjoOeTZsBY&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Saff and Totik.

Answer (score 7):

I really recommend the book [Potential Theory in the complex plane"](http://books.google.ca/books?id=bukn-Rs-t3sC&pg=PR9&lpg=PR9&dq=potential+theory+in+the+complex+plane&source=bl&ots=_kLyeM3BMt&sig=7DuH0JZqkx9_qB_1NfesPslI0dY&hl=en&ei=wi_YTtK2IIHv0gGWyJDLDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q&f=false)
 by Thomas Ransford.

It's a very nice book with exercises and it covers each of the 5 points you mentioned.

Comment: +1. I had intended, while in Quebec, to work my way through the book properly... ;)

Comment: Although to be fair, Tom never intended the book as a reference text. It might still be useful to the OP as an indication of where to look next and what one might expect

Answer (score 2):

[Conformal radius of a domain](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Conformal_radius_of_a_domain) and [Transfinite diameter](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Transfinite_diameter) seem to have most of these terms; see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_radius .

Answer (score 2):

For the first two (maybe 3): L. Ahlfors: *Conformal Invariants: Topics in Geometric Function Theory*

Answer (score 2):

Goluzin, Geometric theory of functions of a complex variable, contains a very comprehensive
discussion of transfinite diameter, Fekete points etc.
Ransford's book mentioned above is also very nice.

Answer (score 0):

J. B. Garnett, D. E. Marshall: *Harmonic Measure*
And also Carleson's (I don't remember the name of the book) book contains at least first two.